# How do I identify Interaction in a column and take sum based on values in two other columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 Tables-
Table 1

```
Customer ID | Date       | Score | Score Factor
------------+------------+-------+-------------
       100  | 2014-10-10 |   15  |         .25
       100  | 2014-12-12 |   25  |         .35
       100  | 2014-08-08 |   35  |         .65
       100  | 2014-09-08 |   45  |         .55
       100  | 2014-01-10 |   15  |         .25
       100  | 2014-12-12 |   75  |         .85
       100  | 2014-08-08 |   85  |         .65
       100  | 2015-09-08 |   45  |         .55
       200  | 2014-10-10 |   45  |         .25
       200  | 2014-12-12 |   55  |         .35
       200  | 2014-08-08 |   35  |         .65
       200  | 2014-09-08 |   45  |         .55
       200  | 2014-01-10 |   55  |         .25
```

Table 2
`Score | Group# | Group Label
-------+--------+-----------+
    10 |      1 |  Superior |
    15 |      1 |  Superior |
    25 |      1 |  Superior |
    35 |      2 |  Mediocre |
    55 |      2 |  Mediocre |
    65 |      3 |  Poor     |
    75 |      3 |  Poor     |
    85 |      4 |  Critical |`

Table 3

```
Interaction  | Group label  | Group label  | Final Score Factor
-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
    INT1     |   Superior   |   Medicocre  |        .80
    INT2     |   Superior   |   Poor       |        .90
    INT3     |   Poor       |   Critical   |        .95
```

Based on these tables, here's what I need to find

Identify whether a 'score' for a 'customer ID' belongs to any group for a particular Year

From Table 1 and Table 2-
Customer 100 for year 2014 has scores of-

- 15, 25 - Group label "Superior"
- 35 - Group label "Mediocre"
- 45 - ***No Group***

Once The Groups have been identified, From Table 3, identify if the groups have Interactions and Map Corresponding 'Final Score Factor'.

Customer 100 has score which belong to Group label "Superior" and "Mediocre". Therefore, INT1 exists and Corresponding 'score factor' is .80.

So the expected result table should be as follows-

```
Customer ID |  Date      | Score| Score Factor| Group#| Group label| Interaction  | Final Score Factor
-------------+------------+------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------------+------------------
100         | 2014-10-10 | 15   | .25         | 1     | Superior   | INT1         |   .80
100         | 2014-12-12 | 25   | .35         | 1     | Superior   | INT1         |   .00
100         | 2014-08-08 | 35   | .65         | 2     | Mediocre   | INT1         |   .00
100         | 2014-08-08 | 45   | .55         | NULL  | Null       | Null         |   .55
100         | 2014-12-12 | 75   | .85         | 3     | Poor       | INT3         |   .95
100         | 2014-08-08 | 85   | .65         | 4     | Critical   | INT3         |   .00
```

NOTE:

1. The 'Final Interaction Score' is accounted only once per interaction. Repeating Values are made equal to .00
2. If the Score factor does not belong to any Interaction, the same Score is carry forwarded as Final Score Factor (Row 4) in the above example

Now, I have to take the Sum of the 'Final Score Factors' per customer per year.
Therefore from the results table(above),

Resultant Score = .80 + .55 + .95

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3470178/juan-carlos-oropeza - Can you please refer this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the way you're supposed to map to the Interactions table. I made some table variables for your input as follows:

```
declare @customers table (id int, thedate date, score int, scorefactor varchar(5) )
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-10-10',15,'.25')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-12-12',25,'.35')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-08-08',35,'.65')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-09-08',45,'.55')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-01-10',15,'.25')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-12-12',75,'.85')
insert into @customers values(100,'2014-08-08',85,'.65')
insert into @customers values(100,'2015-09-08',45,'.55')
insert into @customers values(200,'2014-10-10',45,'.25')
insert into @customers values(200,'2014-12-12',55,'.35')
insert into @customers values(200,'2014-08-08',35,'.65')
insert into @customers values(200,'2014-09-08',45,'.55')
insert into @customers values(200,'2014-01-10',55,'.25')

declare @scores table (score int, groupno int, grouplabel varchar(10))
insert into @scores values(10,1,'Superior')
insert into @scores values(15,1,'Superior')
insert into @scores values(25,1,'Superior')
insert into @scores values(35,2,'Mediocre')
insert into @scores values(55,2,'Mediocre')
insert into @scores values(65,3,'Poor')
insert into @scores values(75,3,'Poor')
insert into @scores values(85,4,'Critical')

declare @interactions table(interaction varchar(5), grouplabel1 varchar(10), grouplabel2 varchar(10), finalscorefactor varchar(5))
insert into @interactions values('INT1', 'Superior', 'Mediocre', '.80')
insert into @interactions values('INT2', 'Superior', 'Poor', '.90')
insert into @interactions values('INT3', 'Poor', 'Critical', '.95')
```

Then, I ran a simple query to match up customer scores to groups for the year 2014:

```
select distinct c.id, s.grouplabel
from @customers c
inner join @scores s
on c.score = s.score
where thedate < '2015-01-01' and thedate >= '2014-01-01'
```

The output I get is this:

```
id  | grouplabel
---------------
100 | Critical
100 | Mediocre
100 | Poor
100 | Superior
200 | Mediocre
```

So I'm getting customer 100 having not just superior and mediocre, but also poor and critical. 
Can you explain better how you would match that to the stuff in table 3?

Comment: You are right. Customer Score 100 has Superior, Mediocre, Poor, critical as well as Null. The next step would be to identify (from table 3 ) if there are any interactions. We can see that there are two interactions - Superior+Mediocre AND Poor+Critical. And the final score should be mapped based on this